# Change the List delimiter to something new

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to change the delimiters of a list. So far I have been successful, but am losing ground on one of the actions.

The issue is the with the last element, which is `v`. The code never appends `=""` to the last element. It should not add a comma to it.

**Code:**

```
<cfset foo="t,u,n,f,o,a,c,r,v">
<cfset msg = ListChangeDelims(foo,'="",')>
<cfoutput>#msg#</cfoutput>
```

**Result:**

```
t="",u="",n="",f="",o="",a="",c="",r="",v
```

I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the definition of delimiter.  Anyway, it is relatively easy to fix, just add the last one yourself.

```
<cfset foo="t,u,n,f,o,a,c,r,v">
<cfset msg = ListChangeDelims(foo,'="",')>
<cfset msg &= '=""'>
<cfoutput>#msg#</cfoutput>
```

http://trycf.com/gist/4ac3702b74bd79b5d1f8/

Comment: Alternatively, you could add the comma to the end of "foo" and set includeEmptyValues to true.

Comment: Yes, that would get you very close, but you would still need to lop off the extra comma on the end.

Answer (score 0):

There is always the old fashioned way

```
msg = replace(foo,",","=", "all");
```

Comment: True, but that does not answer the question asked. As Henry pointed out, the function is doing what it is supposed to do.  They simply need to append the extra value manually.